# Visual SVN for Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, visual-studio, svn

We had used **Visual SVN** for Eclipse before starting a new project with **Visual Studio 2017** and now we are looking a similar one for VS. We have look at several version control plugin and tried some of them i.e. **Team Foundation Server**, **AnkhSVN** but we do not think that they fulfilled our requirements. We have many problems while synchronisation and we do not want to use it anymore. So, we are looking a good version control plugin or software similar to **Visual SVN** in **Eclipse** as described below:

- It uses **Windows Server** rather than Linux, etc.
- It should be **free**.
- It should be as useful as Visual SVN as used for Eclipse.

Could you please suggest us some plugin or tool having the features above for Visual Studio 2017 except from AnkhSVN? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: VisualSVN is a plug-in for Visual Studio IDE and there is VisualSVN Server. VisualSVN does not have a plug-in for Eclipse.

Comment: @bahrep Sorry, I am confused. What is your suggestion? If you have knowledge about this issue, could you please post an answer instead of correcting words???

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualSVNLimited.VisualSVN-Subversionintegration

Comment: @bahrep I think you did not read the question well. I am looking a free version, but this seems to be limited for free usage. Any idea?

Comment: VisualSVN plug-in is free if your computer is not on AD domain.

Comment: Just for the first 30 days. Later it is not free.

Comment: We are in AD, so we need another solution :(